# Finding substrings enclosed within first brackets

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which is as following:

```
" I wanted my friends (he), (she), (they) around"
```

I want to get a list which will have `["he", "she", "they"]`.

Following is my code:

```
copy = " (he), (she), (they)"
x = re.findall(r'^{.}$', copy)
```

but this gives me an empty list as output.

I also tried the following:

```
import re

copy = '{he},{she}, {they}'
x = re.findall(r'\{([^]]*)\}', copy)
print(x)
```

But in this case, the output is:

```
['he},{she}, {they']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\((\w+)\)` (any succession of word characters surrounded by parentheses):

```
import re
re.findall('\((\w+)\)', your_string)
```

input: `your_string = " I wanted my friends (he), (she), (they) around"`

output: `['he', 'she', 'they']`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you have round bracket `(` `)` in your example not curly bracket `{` `}` secondly `^` denotes start of line or string (depending on mode) whilst your bracketed expressions are inside, thirdly `$` denotes end of line or string (depending on mode) whilst your bracketed expressions are inside. You should do

```
import re
text =  " I wanted my friends (he), (she), (they) around"
print(re.findall(r'\((.+?)\)',text))
```

output

```
['he', 'she', 'they']
```

Note that I used so-called raw-string to avoid need of excessive escaping (see [`re` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for further discussion) and need to use `\(` and `\)` to denote literal ( and literal ) as otherwise ( and ) denote group, which is also used in above pattern. `.+?` means match non-greedily one or more of any characters, `?` is important to avoid single match `he), (she), (they`.